# iMacros: #EANF# extracted at wrong row

Tags: firefox, web-scraping, imacros, extract

I am extracting company information from a website; span tags with `company`, `address` and `phone` as classes. Each page on the websites contains 5 companies.

Sometimes `address` or `phone` is not avalible and I should get `#EANF#` as an extraction. But instead, I get the extraction of the upcoming company and `#EANF#` is being pushed down to the buttom.

For example I should get this:

```
Company name 1, Company adress 1, Company phone 1
Company name 2, #EANF#, Company phone 2
Company name 3, Company adress 3, #EANF#
Company name 4, Company adress 4, Company phone 4
Company name 5, Company adress 5, Company phone 5
```

But I get this:

```
Company name 1, Company adress 1, Company phone 1
Company name 2, Company adress 3, Company phone 2
Company name 3, Company adress 4, Company phone 4
Company name 4, Company adress 5, Company phone 5
Company name 5, #EANF#, #EANF#
```

Here is my iMacros code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE pages.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1

' pages.csv contains

' http://website.com/page1
' http://website.com/page2
' http://website.com/page3
' etc..

SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0

URL GOTO={{!COL1}}

WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='company']/a)[1]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[1]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='phone'])[1]" EXTRACT=HTM
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=saved_data_{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='company']/a)[2]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[2]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='phone'])[2]" EXTRACT=HTM
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=saved_data_{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='company']/a)[3]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[3]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='phone'])[3]" EXTRACT=HTM
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=saved_data_{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='company']/a)[4]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[4]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='phone'])[4]" EXTRACT=HTM
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=saved_data_{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='company']/a)[5]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[5]" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='phone'])[5]" EXTRACT=HTM
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=saved_data_{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

Comment: It’s very likely that in the html-code there’s no class=’address’ or class=’phone’ where you expect to get #EANF# as an extractor, so the macro evidently extracts the info of an upcoming company.

Comment: In iMacros `#EANF#` is extracted as a indicator that what you were looking for wasen't found. It should not take the upcoming company.

Comment: Sure! Take a look at this. If in the html-code there's no `class=’address’` for the 2nd company, your code `TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[2]" EXTRACT=HTM` corresponds to the 3rd company, `TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[3]" EXTRACT=HTM` corresponds to the 4th company etc. And therefore `TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[5]" EXTRACT=HTM` is not found (because there are only 4 address items on the page) and you're apparently getting `#EANF#`.

Comment: I understand now, you solved my problem. Changed `TAG XPATH="(/html//span[@class='address'])[13]" EXTRACT=HTM` to `TAG XPATH="/html//li[@class='hit-item'][13]//span[@class='address']"  EXTRACT=HTM`. Thank you!